# Circle coverage percent

Tags: image-processing, geometry

Is there any simple algorithm for finding out coverage percent of two intersecting circles?

We have center and radius defined.

[image]

Comment: What is your input data ? Center and radius of the circles ? Just an image ?

Comment: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Su12/Carreras/EMAT6690/Essay2/essay2.html or be lazy and fill one with red, the other with blue and count the magenta pixels :-)

Comment: Find the pixel positions `(x, y)` of all pixels in circle 1 and circle 2. Pixel positions occurring in both the circles is the intersected region

Comment: The simple algorithm is to calculate the areas and then to calculate the coverage percentage in exactly the same way as it is shown on the picture in your question. What's your specific problem?